# have 2 git repository in project folder, how to delete them and upload the project to git (MacOS)?

Tags: git, github

I am newbie with MacOS and here is my problem.

I created a repository on git as this https://github.com/xxx/example.git and they gave me those command to upload the project to this git, ofcourse

```
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git branch -M main
git remote add origin https://github.com/xxx/example.git
git push -u origin main
```

but, my problem is, when I use this command git init, my computer gave me this problem :

> Reinitialized existing Git repository in /Users/anhbui/Documents/Hoc HTLM, CSS tu Zero den Hero/bai 88 mobile submenu fix bug/.git/

And when I use this command to check : `find ./ -name '.git'`

There are 2 things in my folder :

.//example/.git

.//.git

I searched on internet and they said to me that I must delete those to commit my folder. And I used this command to delete it : `rm -r .//.git`

But, it gave me those things : so many things and never end, so I can not delete this folder :

> override r--r--r--  anhbui/staff for .//.git//objects/d6/3d06038716392b9d9cdee533b6cf97369d6685?

Could you please give me some solutions to solve this problem ? And give me some links to tell me how to upload project to git (Mac) ? Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

> ... when I use this command git init, my computer gave me this problem:
>
> ```
> Reinitialized existing Git repository in /Users/anhbui/Documents/Hoc HTLM, CSS tu Zero den Hero/bai 88 mobile submenu fix bug/.git/
> ```

This is not necessarily a *problem* or an *error*.  It is merely an *informational message*.  What it tells you is that you *already have a Git repository here*, and Git has simply updated any template files.  If you have not customized your entire-computer-Git-installation template files since you created the repository, this will mean that Git has not changed *anything*.

You *can* remove this `.git` directory (and your attempt to do so has probably damaged it already): just use the "force" (`-f`) option with `rm`:

```
rm -r -f .git
```

(or, slightly shorter, `rm -rf .git`).  Note that this will *permanently and completely destroy the existing repository*<sup>1</sup> so you had better be absolutely certain you do not want it at this point.

> There are 2 things in my folder :
>
> ```
> .//example/.git
> .//.git
> ```

The fact that you have both `example/.git` *and* `.git` suggests that you are working in the wrong directory: that you wanted to be working in `./example`, so that the Git repository would be `.git`.  But since you're one level higher than that, you've done some damage to the existing repository in `/Users/anhbui/Documents/Hoc HTLM, CSS tu Zero den Hero/bai 88 mobile submenu fix bug/`.

---

<sup>1</sup>If you have Time Machine backing up your mac, you can use Time Machine to recover, but this is outside the scope of this answer.